# Javac - terminal arguments?

Tags: java

I know you use `javac` to compile and `java` to run (i believe i am right on that one) ans then you have `jar` to run jar files. I am having a small issue with my application as it requires me to pass it terminal arguments. so: `javac --port=47000 MyApp.java` does not work.

in this case it requires the command line arguments of `--port=47000`. Every where I look states you compile, then you run and when you run you pass in terminal arguments. But that seems wrong - as when you compile you do `javac <options> <filename>`.

I have read the [Javac Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) and have found nothing.

So how do I compile while passing in terminal arguments? the exact error I get is:

```
javac: invalid flag: --port=47000
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Comment: I assume your parameter is needed at runtime, not compile time. So pass it to `java`, not `javac`.

Comment: `<options>` means options _for javac_, not for your program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't pass your application arguments when you compile with `javac`.  You pass them on the command line when running them with `java`, *after* you specify the class to run:

```
javac MyApp.java
java MyApp --port=47000
```

Here's [Java's tutorial on command-line arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

Comment: I figured it was run javac before, but - I have arguments that must be passed in or else javac explodes being like "I wanted an int, you gave me null) ...

Comment: Then you have a compiler error that you must fix before you can even run your program.

Comment: @TheWebs by any chance it says `javac: invalid flag: --port=47000`?

Answer (score 1):

> Every where I look states you compile, then you run and when you run you pass in terminal arguments. But that seems wrong

I'm afraid it's not wrong, and if you do exactly what everyone says then it will work.

```
javac MyApp.java
java MyApp --port=47000
```

Why did you not believe everywhere else that you looked?